# Regarding regex match in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to match all the words with $ & \$. I am not bale to print them using a single regex. Need help.

```
import re

lines = ["1:RUN This is my $value and $answer",
         "2:RUN This is my ${value}",
         "3:RUN This is my \$value"
         ]

for i in lines:
    try:
        match = re.findall(r".*((\\\\)?\${?\w+}?).*", i)
    except AttributeError:
        match = "None"

    print(match)
```

I am getting the below result.:

```
[]
[]
['\\$value']
```

Also, i am getting two backslash instead of one.
One more question, To avoid null, we use try/except, but it works for one group at a time. Is it possible to match all the groups with single try/except statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this pattern `r'[$]\S*'`

**Ex:**

```
import re

lines = ["1:RUN This is my $value and $answer",
         "2:RUN This is my ${value}",
         "3:RUN This is my \$value",
         "4:Hello World"
         ]

for i in lines:
    match = re.findall(r'[$]\S*', i)
    print(match)
```

**Output:**

```
['$value', '$answer']
['${value}']
['$value']
[]
```

---

*Without Regex.*

```
print( [j for i in lines for j in i.split() if j.startswith(("$", r"\$"))] )
-->['$value', '$answer', '${value}', '\\$value']
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. Actually, my goal is to check if $ is escaped in the lines or not.So, i want \$value to printed also. I need to run a if/else condition to check for \. This is just a sample list. I have a huge list to check. And why we are getting double backslash '\\$value'